# True MVVM and third party controls

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, infragistics, xamdatagrid

In a True MVVM model we do not expect any code behind in xaml.cs also we do not expect viewModel to have refernece of view.
However all third party controls do not provide good support for True MVVM.

In my case I am using Infragistics xamDatagrid control and I want to export its data to excel. The only way I can export data to excel of data grid is by using following code:

```
xamDataGridExcelExporter.xamDataGridExcelExporter xamDataGridExcelExporter1 =       
   new xamDataGridExcelExporter.xamDataGridExcelExporter();   
xamDataGridExcelExporter1.Export(**this.xamDataGrid1**,   
   @"C:\Excel\ExportFile.xls");
```

However, XamDataGridExcelExporter takes input as this.xamDataGrid. xamDataGrid is part of View not viewModel.
*So how can we handle such kind of cases where we need instance of view in viewModel*.

Comment: Can I suggest going back to the datasource instead of to the data display control? Meaning requery the database or somesuch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a wrapper around xamDataGrid that has a dependencyproperty called filename. The viewmodel can then bind to this property.  When the xamDataGrid detects a change on the filename property it can then execute the code you suggested.  Afterwards reset the filename property for further notification.

This solution keeps out the code from you code behind and makes the xamDataGrid responsible for exporting its data.

-------edit---------

A second solution can make use of the MVVM light messenger class.  In stead of declaring a dependency property, make your wrapper listen to a message.  When the viewmodel sends the message (which could for example have the filename as parameter) the wrapper can then execute the code.

eg

```
public class ExportableXamDataGrid: XamDataGrid
{
    public ExportableXamDataGrid():base()
    {
        Messenger.Default.Register<string>(this,"ExportExcel",ExportFile);
    }

    private void ExportFile(string file)
    {
        xamDataGridExcelExporter.xamDataGridExcelExporter xamDataGridExcelExporter1 =       
        new xamDataGridExcelExporter.xamDataGridExcelExporter();   
        xamDataGridExcelExporter1.Export(**this.xamDataGrid1**,   
           @"C:\Excel\ExportFile.xls");

    }
}
```

Then in your viewmodel you can do:

```
 Messenger.Default.Send(@"C:\Excel\ExportFile.xls","ExportExcel");
```

There are many solutions to your problem, all of which you do not have to start writing logic in your view.

http://www.lucbos.net/2011/06/using-codebehind-in-mvvm.html

Comment: Both solution1 and solution2 looks to be a good fit here. Could you provide a code snipet for solution2.

Comment: I edited my answer.  I do not have the infragistics library so your implementation might differ a bit though the grand scheme of things should be the same.  Should the XamDatagrid be sealed then you can make a wrapper.  The down side off using a wrapper is that you'll have to declare all the dependency properties you use in xaml and pass them trough.

Comment: Thanks @Luc Bos. Thats a clean solution and shall be useful not only in this case but where ever the third party control is not MVVM compatible.

Answer (score 9):

It is a common misconception that MVVM forbids code-behind.  The truth is that code-behind is not reusable and it is inseparable from the view, so it cannot be unit tested without automation.  But it does have its uses.

There is **nothing inherently bad** about code-behind.  In fact, it's not much different than **all the other code** your write in support of your view like converters, custom controls, etc.  None of this code can be tested by your view-model unit tests.  The only difference with code-behind is that it is less reusable.  But it's still **part of your view** and views are **not bad**.

In general, the **absence** of code-behind is a good indicator of a clean separation between the view and the view-model.  However the **presence** of some code-behind in an otherwise clean design usually merely indicates something that is hard to do with the standard controls and data binding and commands.

In your case, exporting the `XamDataGrid` **is definitely view-specific**.  It has to do precisely with the third-party library you have chosen for the view.  So it **makes perfect sense** that it should not be part of the view-model.

If you are are still **dead set against** any code-behind, you can use behaviors, such as [ACB](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/12/13/attachedcommandbehavior-v2-aka-acb/) or [Blend Behaviors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff724013%28v=expression.40%29.aspx) to write functionality that you would otherwise put into the code-behind.  Just realize that even behaviors are **still part of the view**, only more reusable that code-behind.

Comment: +1. Just as a matter of fact, setting up components like ACB or Blend Behaviors is often very difficult and sometimes I can't understand why a developer should do so much effort for reproducing simple behaviors (eg. a double-click...) without adding a single-line in code-behind...

Comment: I agree on the fact that sometimes there is no choice but to write logic in your view but I do not think this is the case.  One should always try to write logic that has nothing to do with UI away from the view.  Just because this code needs a UI element as parameter does not mean it's UI code.  Adding code to the codebehind of the view will encourage the broken window effect.

Comment: @Damascus & @Rick, the point here is not if code behind is good or bad, the point here is that many third party controls do not support MVVM. To cover these cases we end up writing lot of code that is nothing but work arounds. And these workarounds turn up to be very specific in every case. To me these are nothing but hacks. My idea here is to understand if there is a generic or cleaner approach to such problems.

Comment: @Pradeep: By all means, use the workarounds provided by your toolkit of choice.  The point is that exporting is still part of your view and is untestable without automation.

Comment: @Rick: Agreed I could have done with view only. no need to involve viewModel. However in my case the button that requests export is in a different view. If both Event and grid were belonging to the same view, I would have taken your words. hope that clarifies.

Comment: @Luc Bos: I agree with your point here. As long as we can implement the features needed in the ViewModel we should (and even we have to) do it. But in this case and as Rick said, the problem is purely View-specific and can therefore be written in code-behind

Answer (score 2):

I'd use code behind because the 'problem' is cause by the view so I would keep it there.

Yes, that will break MVVM but using these controls it is already broken. By keeping the solution in the code behind you willl keep the ViewModel as clean as possible so when the controls do support MVVM it is easier to clean up.

Answer (score 1):

I'd strongly recommend to use System.Windows.Interactivity.Interaction.Triggers in XAML and use the Event trigger to call a event of XamDataGrid and use 'CallDataMethod' which will call a custom method that you will create on the ViewModel. The best thing in this is that you will get the object(XamDataGrid) reference as sender.

This will be purely MVVM and you will be able to acheive your goal. Also, i would recommend to use WPF DataGrid which is very light weight as compared to XamDataGrid. Only use XamDataGrid if you are using some major functionalities provided by this control, cuz just to initialize this UI Element the processor takes 200 milliseconds or may be more.

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedCellsChanged">
                                    <is:CallDataMethod Method="YourMethodNameInViewModel" />
                                </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

And in the View Model your Method i.e.

```
public void YourMethodNameInViewModel(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {}
```

Comment: My requirement is opposite. I need to call view's datagrid from viewmodel.

Comment: You must be providing some UI ELement i.e button on the View which provides the user with this export to excel option?

Comment: the button is in a different view. if it was on the same view i would have not involved the viewmodel at all since it would have been a pure view activity.

Comment: ok, then Event Aggregation or iMessenger implementation would solve your issue.

Comment: As per the article given on Event Aggregation by Microsoft - this functionality can be applied independently on any MVVM structure

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry too much about it. Yes, having "heavy" views is opposed to the ideas of MVVM (thin views, testability). But there are always exceptions to the rule.

The decision here is using the "free/existing" XAMDataGrid export functionality or write your own MVVM version of it (which resides in the ViewModel).

If you choose Option1, you'd need to cache the View object within the ViewModel (use ctor injection) in addition the usual approach of setting View.DataContext = ViewModel and relying on data-binding to handle the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of keeping the Excel Exporter in **ViewModel** you can place it in a [**Behavior**](http://www.jayway.com/2013/03/20/behaviors-in-wpf-introduction/) around the event you are triggering the export.

create a DataPresenter(xamdatagrid) type dependency property in your behavior and bind that to your existing xamdatagrid in XAMLcode to get access of your xamdatagrid. This way you'll functionally achieve and ViewModel will be free of UI objects.

```
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <behav:ExcelExporterBehavior MyDataPresenter="{Binding ElementName=myxamdatagrid,Mode=OneTime}"></behav:ExcelExporterBehavior>
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

if **MyDataPresenter** is the property in **ExcelExporterBehavior** behavior which is set to any other UI control (say any button to export).